# laptop will not boot hdd - samsung 13" ultrabook 5 series

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios, updates

This is a long one. I want to include troubleshooting I did.
Im running windows 8.1, I downloaded the Samsung SW updater software and it gives me a whole list of updates including the Bios update. So I run it. Why not?
Now it will not boot up the hdd. It does a few loops and then gives me the option to either continue looping or press f4 for recovery. Well, naturally I pull out the hdd and connect it as a slave to another system and backup the files before doing a recovery. No issues accessing the hdd.
Pop it back in, same loop, same msg. I press f4. Recovery will not run! I try holding f4 and it continues to loop.
I can access the bios by holding f2 or waiting for the boot options and selecting setup. So I try to reset bios defaults. Save. Reboot. Nothing changes.
The ultrabook doesnt have an optical drive. So I use an external,  which is now not detected in the bios, Im guessing because of the reset.
Ive tried using other functinal hdds. None work. You can always hear it start to spin up the hdd and half a second later, click, fail. No matter which hdd. Cant use a bootable USB or sd card either. 
Maybe my motherboard is fried??
Thoughts??

Comment: It's probably a "Secure Boot"/"EFI" issue rather than a hardware failure. Can you get to the BIOS/EFI screens to change BIOS options?

Comment: Thank Big Chris. Yes I can. What do you suggest I change?

Comment: Big Chris u are awesome! I looked at those settings, disabled Secure Boot,  set it to UEFI and CSM OS. Now it boots up! Im new to this site, I have to figure out how to give u positive feedback/points or whatever.  Thanks dude!! I thought I was screwed.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the the BIOS screens and disable Secure Boot. Many devices have this as "CSM", "CSM Boot" or "UEFI and CSM OS" which allows legacy boot devices to boot. You may have to disable Secure Boot to be able to change the options to select CSM boot.